# Nginx + uwsgi... 502 bad gateway

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

So I am trying to set up Nginx with uwsgi for my Django app.

Here is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user       richard richard;  ## Default: nobody
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/log/nginx/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
  include   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  include   /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  index     index.html index.htm;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts

  include   /etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost.conf;
}
```

And my /etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost.conf:

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost.conf
upstream django {
  # connect to this socket
  server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}

server {
  # the port your site will be served on
  listen      80;
  # the domain name it will serve for
  server_name localhost;
  charset     utf-8;

  client_max_body_size 2M;

  location /media  {
    alias /usr/local/django-app/media;
  }

  location /static {
    alias /usr/local/django-app/static;
  }

  # finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
  location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
  }
}
```

When I go to localhost I get:

```
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 502 Bad Gateway
2013-12-22 03:08:56 ERROR 502: Bad Gateway
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Django app is not running. Start it (and make sure you got the socket path correct).